# update querySelectorAll nodeList after added element dynamically

Tags: javascript, event-delegation, selectors-api

I have a function that select all elements inside an specific class through `document.querySelectorAll(theClass + ' > *');` but need to listen in case some element is added inside this DOM block but after fired the function. 
Here is an example:

```
function controlElems(cl){
  var nl = document.querySelectorAll(cl + ' > *');
  console.log(nl.length);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var list = document.querySelector('.list');
  controlElems('.list');

  // This element added after controlElems() 
  // won't be inside the nodeList

  var newElm = document.createElement('li');
  newElm.id = "id5";
  newElm.innerHTML ="Item 5: after";
  list.appendChild(newElm);
});
```

example also [here](http://jsbin.com/diviyusufe/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Take a look at the `MutationObserver`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Thanks! Also I'm trying MutationEvents (and reading that there are some pref issues): http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the MutationObserver is a replacement of the MutationEvent, so you should check if the browsers you're targeting support the feature!

Comment: in last FF, Safari and Chrome MutationEvent works well.